# Non-natural dimension of sets

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, exponentiation

This question is not for an exercise or a task, but just mathematical curiosity:

In Mathematics we are used to work with sets such as $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, etc. However, we also use their "powers" provided by the cartesian product ($\mathbb{R}^n$ for example). However, I wonder if somebody knows whether it is possible to define "non-natural" "powers" of this sets, or of any set apart from the usual ones, the same as with the set of real numbers, where exponentiation can be extended to any number like for example, $2^\pi$ or $3^{5.43}$. Is it possible to define stuff like $\mathbb{R}^{\frac{2}{5}}$, $\mathbb{Q}^\pi$ or $[0,1]^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}}$? Does it makes sense? Has anybody thought about it before? Not only that, but if they exist, is it possible to equip these sets with an operation to create an algebraic structure? As a lover and still student of algebraic structures, it would be great for me that groups like $(\mathbb{R}^{\pi},+)$ could be created, or even more.

Postdata: I don't know which tags use for this question, so please don't downvote just for this.

Comment: Real number exponentiation and Cartesian product of copies of a set are very different beasts. They share notation only coincidentally. I don't think there is any research going on such topic. Or at least its the very first time I hear about such idea. The closest thing I can think of is the [fractal dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension) (which indeed can be any real number) but I'm not sure how well it answers your question.

Comment: You can generalize to $A^B$ with $A$ and $B$ both sets where we interpret $X^n$ as being $X$ to the power of a set with $n$ elements.

Comment: @CyclotomicField This doesn't answer the question, though, since the OP asks for rational or real numbers as exponents. Ok in ZFC rational and real numbers are sets, but then the definition would depend on the "implementation details" of the number constructions, which is no proper math. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: "I don't know which tags use for this question" Yes, it is a bit difficult. I added *elementary set theory* as a tag. But *category theory* is perhaps also appropriate, given my answer in particular (but maybe this is just because I see everything through the lens of category theory ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a set $X$ we may define $\sqrt{X}$ as a set (if it exists) with $\sqrt{X}^2 \cong X$. Here, recall that two sets are isomorphic when there is a bijection (=isomorphism) between them, and $Y^2$ is the cartesian product of $Y$ with itself.

Some easy observations:

- If $X$ is finite with $n$ elements, then $\sqrt{X}$ exists iff $n$ is a square number.
- If $X$ is infinite, then $\sqrt{X}$ exists, and in fact $\sqrt{X} \cong X$. This is because for every infinite set $X$ we have $X^2 \cong X$.
- If $\sqrt{X}$ exists, then it is uniquely determined up to isomorphism.

The main obstacle, though, is that there is no general, natural construction of $\sqrt{X}$ (by this I mean a functor from the category of sets which have a root to the category of sets). I think that this makes this notion pretty much useless. In particular, when thinking of $Y^2$ as the set of maps from a $2$-element set to $Y$, we cannot define $\sqrt{X}$ as set of maps from a $\frac{1}{2}$-element set (what should that be?) to $X$, at least not classically*.

A similar definition works in every [cartesian cateory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+monoidal+category). For example, if $G$ is a group, we can define $\sqrt{G}$ as a group with $\sqrt{G}^2 \cong G$ (isomorphism of groups), if it exists. This propery is much more restrictive when compared to the category of sets. Also, $\sqrt{G}$ will not be uniquely determined anymore by [MO/150793](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150793) (it is in the case of finite groups, though).

Similar remarks apply to the notion of $\sqrt[n]{X}$. For example, [MO/10128](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3) has examples of abelian groups with $A \cong \sqrt[3]{A} \not\cong \sqrt{A}$. The (must-read!) paper [Seven Trees in One](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9405205) by Andreas Blass shows that the set of finite binary trees $T$ satisfies $T \cong \sqrt[7]{T}$, or more precisely that you can write down an isomorphism $T^7 \cong T$ explicitly instead of just bailing out with the argument that $T$ is infinite.

In ring theory, the square root notation is already taken for something else, though: If $I$ is an ideal of a ring $R$, then $\sqrt{I}$ is the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_ideal) of $I$. This operation is quite different from the square roots of numbers, though. For example, $\sqrt{\sqrt{I}}=\sqrt{I}$, and in $R=\mathbb{Z}$ we have $\sqrt{n}=\langle p_1 \cdots p_s \rangle$ when $p_1,\dotsc,p_s$ are the distinct primes dividing $n$.

*Janelidze and Street have investigated [real sets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.08787v2) (Tbilisi Mathematical Journal 10(3) (2017) 23-49) which presumably (I didn't read it in detail yet) enables us to find a **"set" $S$ with $\frac{1}{2}$ elements**. Then the "set" of maps $S \to X$ (if that exists in their framework) could be a version of $\sqrt{X}$, and $S \times X$ could be a version of $\frac{1}{2} X$.

Comment: I remember reading a paper that constructs for sets $A,B$ from every isomorphism $2A \to 2B$ explicitly an isomorphism $A \to B$ (where $2A = A \sqcup A$). Maybe it was also $A^2 \to B^2$, I don't remember, and can't find it right now. These questions of course are very much related to the uniqueness of the (first) notion of a square root resp. "half set".

Comment: Ah yeah found it. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605779