# Fractional and irrational "operators"

Tags: calculus

Another question rounding my mind:

Yesterday I asked a question about the possible notion of "fractional" or "irrational" powers of sets like $\mathbb{R}^{5.667}$ ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803263/non-natural-dimension-of-sets)). I have been successfully answered, but I have give it another thought and I wondered if this "non-natural" dimensional number could be extended to some operators. For example, one usually consider $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$, which is the operator related to the second partial derivative. Or, to make more simpler, in one variable, the operator $D_n(f(x)) = \frac{d^nf}{dx^n}$, which is simply the $n$-derivative of a function (of course, assuming that $f \in C^{n})$. Is is possible to define things such as $D_{\frac{2}{5}}(f(x))$, or $D_\pi(f(x))$, or integrating a "non-integer" times a function, or taking the Laplace transform? More generally, is it possible to extend this to all fields of mathematics? I guess that if it has been possible with factorials, why not with these concepts?

Comment: The answer is "sometimes this generalisation is possible and some of those times it is interesting".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus